# Outlook desktop notifications not showing up

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-outlook, notifications

The pop-up desktop notification and sound for Outlook have stopped showing up on one of my computers.  Desktop alerts and sounds are enabled in Outlook settings, notification from Outlook are enabled in Win10 notifications settings, new emails go to the inbox, and I'm not using quiet hours.  Notably, when I first detected this issue, I discovered that Windows 10's notification settings had been disabled for Outlook at some point (AFAIK, I didn't do this).  Re-enabling this setting hasn't brought back pop-up alerts.  Rebooting had no effect.

System details:

- Windows 10 Enterprise
- Outlook Office 365 ProPlus, version 1903 (build 11425.20202 if this means anything)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I disabled all (or at least most?) of the notification-oriented settings, specifically:   (A) desktop alerts in Outlook, (B) showing an envelope icon in the taskbar, and (C) Outlook notifications in Windows notification settings.  I then re-enabled them. I didn't track the order because I didn't expect it to work.  But, after restarting Outlook, it did.

Answer (score 2):

**Update: 6/25/2021**
Turning on Cached Exchange Mode in the Outlook settings and also right-clicking the EXE and Troubleshooting Compatibility to an older version of Outlook fixed my issue.

**Original Answer**
The way I got it working was to set up the Windows Mail application with my Outlook account. It still doesn't work in Outlook, but at least I can see notifications.

Answer (score 1):

Please confirm whether the new incoming messages are in the Inbox folder of the mailbox because new mail desktop only works for the default inbox.

You can refer to this thread to check if all the settings are correct:[[Troubleshooting] New mail desktop alert not working](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/cd8804a8-65fd-4b22-bf7a-5063984c7b23/troubleshooting-new-mail-desktop-alert-not-working?forum=outlook)

If issue persists, we can [repair outlook data file](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/repair-outlook-data-files-pst-and-ost-25663bc3-11ec-4412-86c4-60458afc5253) to test the result.

Besides, for windows 10, there is an option called Quiet Hours in side tab. It will block all active alerts. If it is turned on, please turn off this option.

Comment: Confirmed none of those non-standard situations applied to my case.  I just tried disabling all of the notification-oriented settings, then re-enabling them.  I didn't track the order b/c I didn't expect it to work, but, at least after restarting Outlook, it did.  I'll wait a little for other answers, then self-answer if nothing else has arisen.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem for me (Win 10 + Outlook 365). I had to reset the Outlook profile to solve it: File > Info > Account Settings > Manage Profiles, added a new profile with the same settings of the existing one and using it solved for me.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Send/Receive tab up top above the ribbon and choose the Send/Receive Groups and from that list put a check next to Disable Scheduled Send/Receive.

This worked for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).